# Cookie Authentication not redirecting after user login in asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas

I can't quite wrap my head around this problem, When a user navigates to the admin URL, they are redirected to admin specific account/login page (located in admin Area's folder). But when the admin logs into the admin controller that is decorated with the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "Backend")] attribute, the page just reloads with returnUrl. It seems like the application does not recognize the logged-in user to grant access to the admin controller actions, can't figure out why. Please help!

**Admin Controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "Backend")]
[Area("Admin")] 
public class AdminController : Controller
{
  private readonly IAdminRepository _adminInterface;
  private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
  private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

  public AdminController(IAdminRepository adminInterface, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, 
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
 {
    _adminInterface = adminInterface;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
 }

 public IActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

}

**Account Controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

public AccountController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, 
    UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if(user != null && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin")))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt");
            return View(model);
        }
        if(user != null && !user.EmailConfirmed && (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password)))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Confirm Email Address");
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "admin");
            } 
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt");
    }
    return View(model);
}
}
```

**Dashboard Controller**

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Authorize(Role = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "Backend")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddControllersWithViews(); 


    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    }) 
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddScoped<IAdminRepository, AdminRepository>();
    services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie("Backend", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "Backend";
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/account/login/");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/admin/account/logout/"); 
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login/");
    }); 

 }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();


    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "AllAreas",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=admin}/{action=index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
       }); 
   }
```

Comment: What is the behavior when you remove the role and policy from the authorize attribute? Both of your controllers are in admin area, are they intended?

Comment: @YankTHEcode when I remove the role, same thing happens. But when I remove the AuthenticationScheme it works, the thing is, next time a user goes to the admin URL, they are redirected to normal user login. and yes, both controllers are in the admin area.

Comment: Is there any difference in behavior if you use ie vs chrome? If yes then I think you might wanna try to use secure cookie and forcing app to use https. I think these symptoms happen when browser is having issues with cookies. Try using fiddler to trace it might give more hints. Looking at the code nothing obvious comes to mind

Comment: Could be the login path as well, I cant really say for sure United I see a fiddler trace

Comment: @YankTHEcode will it help if I show my server logs?

Comment: If it shows the cookie info then yes